# Dismissing view controllers

Tags: objective-c, swift, viewcontroller, presentviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

If I switch between several views in my app only by using `presentViewController` or `pushViewController` and without using `dismissViewController` or `popViewController`, Can I dismiss presented view controllers at a later stage ? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you don't switch between views by using presentViewCOntroller. You switch the viewControllers.

Comment: When you present it, you dismiss it. When you push it, you pop it. You cannot pop when you don't have a nav controller. You can dismiss at anypoint on anything but not on rootCOntroller.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Thanks for commenting on my question. I understand that i dismiss when i present a view controller. But due to some design constraints(efficient handling of push notification between views) of my app, I cannot always dismiss view controllers. When a new push notification arrives my app crashes if I dismissed a viewController earlier. So instead of dismissing, presenting the viewController solved my issue. It in turn consumed more memory. That's why I asked the question, Can I dismiss viewControllers piled up in memory at a later stage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,You can dismiss the view controller in the later stages of the project , but it depends how you use in your project, like in navigation controller you can use push ,pop and view controller you can have present , dismiss.. etc or else you can't mix up both. For more reference [Check Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html).